# Why I keep getting undefined error in map arrow function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, spotify

I recently just started on a project that utilizes Spotify API. I've been trying to extract artist's IDs with the code I wrote:

```
app.events = function() {
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let artists = $('input[type=search]').val();
    artists = artists.split(',');
    let search = artists.map(artistName => app.searchArtist(artistName));
    $.when(...search)
        .then((...results) => {
            results = results.map(res => res[0].artists.items[0].id);
            console.log(results);
        });
});


app.searchArtist = (artistName) => $.ajax({
url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search',
headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
},
method: 'GET',
dataType: 'json',
data: {
    type: 'artist',
    q: artistName
}
```

The problem is with this line:

```
results = results.map(res => res[0].artists.items[0].id);
```

Every time I try to run the code, it returned `res[0]`is undefined, as shown like this in browser's console:
[res[0] undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WqXv.png)

The array that I'm trying to get is artist ID as shown: 
[artist id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkyl2.jpg)

I don't know why it keeps getting the undefined error. I'm new to javascript and using API. What is the reason for this error? Help please.

Comment: It's because `res` isn't an array, it's a reference to the current element within the array that you're iterating through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be trying to access res[0] when there's no **0** key in *res*.

You should try this approach:

```
results = results.map(res => res.artists.items[0].id);
```

The way [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) works is by calling the specified function for each element in the array and returning the new array without modifying the original.